# White spaces between spans while selecting on Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android

I tried to wrap each word in a span for later processing so when I select all of them on the Desktop browser, everything seems normal.

However, when I open the link on Android browser, it gives random vertical white space between span while I select all text which is annoying

Note:
This may be happen on safari ios too.

```
<body>
    <span>This</span>
    <span> is</span>
    <span> a </span>
    <span> sentence</span>
    <span> where</span>
    <span> each </span>
    <span> word</span>
    <span> is </span>
    <span> inside</span>
    <span> a</span>
    <span> span</span>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: What is this "later processing". It may be that wrapping every word in a span tag is the wrong approach.

Comment: I want to add a <div> at the end of the line break to give some spaces(for a menu) below the clicking line.

Comment: I don't really understand what it is you're trying to do but wrapping each word in a span cannot be the correct way to achieve it. Why not ask a question on how to solve your original problem (the div linebreak menu issue)?

Comment: Yes, I will. About this problem, this still gives a weird space between a span and another element too but it looks less awful so people maybe ignore that

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of any help with this issue. Good luck!